# 一回 job の設定を変更するごとに、 Job Config History に複数個の歴史が刻まれる

Tags: jenkins

JobConfigHistoryPlugin が入った (それ以外にもいろいろ入っている) jenkinsがあります。

一体なにがどうなっているのかわからないのですが、この jenkins の job の設定を変更すると、 Job Config History に複数個の変更履歴が登録される、という現象が起こっています。

なにが原因だと考えられるでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[本家](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33464414/3090068)で聞いてみた結果、ちょうど同じような Jenkins の issue に上がっていて、今は solved らしいです。 DiskUsagePlugin の不具合の様子です。

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22224